how to update an employeev2 in dynamics?
In an azure function  I'm attempting to update an entity in dynamics:
    public  async Task UpdateEmployeeAsync(JObject employee)
    {
        var content = new StringContent(employee.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync($"/data/EmployeesV2", content);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }

I've attempted something like this as well:
var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync($"/data/EmployeesV2/{employee["PersonnelNumber"]}", content);

Each time i get an internal server error response.
I've attempted the same in Postman, with various types of requests:
PATCH
https://xxxxxxxxxxx.dynamics.com/data/EmployeesV2(PersonnelNumber='100059')
BODY
{
    "FirstName": "xxx",
    "LastName": "xxxx",
    "PrimaryContactEmail": "xxxxxxxx.com",
    "PersonnelNumber": "100059",
    "EmploymentLegalEntityId": "0093",
    "EmploymentStartDate": "2021-09-27T00:00:00-05:00",
    "TitleId": " Chief Executive Officer"
}

The response I'm getting is:
{
    "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.dynamics.com/data/EmployeesV2(PersonnelNumber='100059')'. No route data was found for this request."
}

Any idea how to PATCH an EmployeeV2 entity in C#?

dynamics endoint is at /api/data/v9.2/???_EmployeesV2([GUID]). You need to first find GUID of the record, find it using odata query by personnel number. You also need to know schema name of the EmployeeV2 table -- it always has ???_ prefix with some letters.

what do you mean by ???_ ?? what should go there?

@AlexGordon that endpoint is not Dynamics CRM, loos like F&O or Business Central, update the tag based on the exact product

@GuidoPreite i cannot find a tag for f&o

@GuidoPreite someone added tags, though im not sure those are the correct ones. ive also added a bounty

@skfd i might be wrong, but im not seeing any guid in the dataset

Short answer
Use the following request:
PATCH
https://xxxxxxxxxxx.dynamics.com/data/EmployeesV2(PersonnelNumber='100059',EmploymentLegalEntityId='0093',EmploymentId='100059')
BODY
{
    "FirstName": "xxx",
    "LastName": "xxxx",
    "PrimaryContactEmail": "xxxxxxxx.com",
    "PersonnelNumber": "100059",
    "EmploymentLegalEntityId": "0093",
    "EmploymentStartDate": "2021-09-27T00:00:00-05:00",
    "TitleId": " Chief Executive Officer"
}


Note: I had to guess the value for EmploymentId in the URL. In my case it is the same as PersonnelNumber. Make sure to check your data.

Long answer
To update an existing record with a PATCH request, you need to use the canonical URL. This is the URL where the entity set is used with the key properties in parentheses. See also OData services in the D365FO Microsoft documentation.
The question then becomes, what are the key properties of the entity set being used? If you are familiar with the overall data model and have access to a D365FO development environment, you can look at the entity definition in the designer.

If you do not have that information, you can use the metadata document to get the key properties of the entity set. The metadata document is available at the following URL (it may take a while to get the response - for version 10.0.39, it is 39 MB):
https://xxxxxxxxxxx.dynamics.com/data/$metadata

In the metadata document, you can search for the entity set name EmployeesV2 and look for the EntitySet element. This will have a EntityType attribute that will give you the name of the entity type. You can then search for the EntityType element with that name (without the Microsoft.Dynamics.DataEntities. prefix) to get the key properties.
<EntitySet Name="EmployeesV2" EntityType="Microsoft.Dynamics.DataEntities.EmployeeV2">

<EntityType Name="EmployeeV2">
    <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="PersonnelNumber" />
        <PropertyRef Name="EmploymentLegalEntityId" />
        <PropertyRef Name="EmploymentId" />
    </Key>


im very grateful for your answer. thank you. i really appreciate you taking the time
